# flutter display text with cursor

Tags: flutter

I would like to simulate the. way human type in flutter. To be more specific, I would like to display a paragraph of text character by character, and have a cursor following the display of the character. I have the following snippet, but this snippet is only working for the first line of the text, (cursor following the speed of display of text). How can I make it so that it works for all lines of text?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Typing Animation',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TypingScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TypingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TypingScreenState createState() => _TypingScreenState();
}

class _TypingScreenState extends State<TypingScreen> {
  String sentence =
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
  int currentIndex = 0;
  bool showCursor = true;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTypingAnimation();
  }

  void startTypingAnimation() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      setState(() {
        currentIndex++;
        showCursor = !showCursor;
        if (currentIndex > sentence.length) {
          _scrollController.animateTo(
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            curve: Curves.easeOut,
          );
        }
      });
      if (currentIndex < sentence.length) {
        startTypingAnimation();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String displayedText = sentence.substring(0, currentIndex);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Typing Animation'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 300, // Adjust the width according to your needs
                child: Wrap(
                  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      displayedText,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
                    AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: showCursor ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: Text(
                        '|',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

expecting human-like typing be in display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use RichText and put the AnimatedOpacity inside the text at the end.

would be like this:

```
RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
  text: "",
  children: [
    TextSpan(
        text: displayedText,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24, color: Colors.grey)),
    WidgetSpan(
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: showCursor ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: const Text(
          '|',
          style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)),
```